# GEE - Hide scripts for users

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine, web-service

Is there a way to provide use access to my scripts without showing them to the user? I want to provide free services without giving away my code.

Comment: If the "scripts" are JavaScript that runs in the client's browser, how could you ***prevent*** "giving away" the code?

Comment: this comes closest I guess: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/apps